# DWORD and DWORD_PTR on 64 bit machine

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

There are few `*_PTR` types added to the Windows API in order to support Win64's 64bit addressing.

```
SetItemData(int nIndex,DWORD_PTR dwItemData)
```

This API works for both 64 and 32 bit machines when I pass second parameter as `DWORD`.

I want to know, if this particular API will fail on 64 bit machine, if I pass the second parameter as `DWORD`. How can I test the fail scenario?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function will not fail if you pass a `DWORD`, because it fits into a `DWORD_PTR`. A pointer, however, is guaranteed to fit into a `DWORD_PTR` but *not* into a `DWORD` on 64-bit platforms.

Thus, this code is correct:

```
int *before_ptr = new int;
yourListBox.SetItemData(index, (DWORD_PTR) before_ptr);
int *after_ptr = (int *) yourListBox.GetItemData(index);
ASSERT(before_ptr == after_ptr);  // Succeeds.
delete after_ptr;                 // Works.
```

But this code is wrong and will silently truncate the pointer to its lower 32 bits:

```
int *before_ptr = new int;
yourListBox.SetItemData(index, (DWORD) before_ptr);
int *after_ptr = (int *) yourListBox.GetItemData(index);
ASSERT(before_ptr == after_ptr);  // Fails.
delete after_ptr;                 // Undefined behavior, might corrupt the heap.
```

Comment: You are correct the pointer will not fit into DWORD on 64 bit and it will truncate the pointer.How can i test this fail scenario where my pointer will truncate and i will get undesired value.

Comment: I tried this but i am not getting any assertion:                                                                  'CString str("");
 for (int i=0;i < 20;i++)
 {
  str.Format(_T("item string %d"), i);
  XcomboCtr.AddString( str );
 }
 int *before_ptr = new int;

 BOOL bsetItemData= XcomboCtr.SetItemData(0, (DWORD)before_ptr);

 int *after_ptr = (int*)( XcomboCtr.GetItemData(0));
  
 ASSERT(before_ptr == after_ptr);  // Fails.

 delete after_ptr; '

Comment: @Nikhil, assuming you're building in debug mode (the `ASSERT` won't be compiled in release mode), it might mean that your pointer's upper 32 bits are all zeroes. In that case, it will work, but you can't guarantee that all your pointers will be like that.