# What is the use of CListCtrl::GetItemData()?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

Can anybody please help me to know, what is the use of `CListCtrl::GetItemData()` in MFC, VC++ ?

I went through MSDN description but it was not clear enough.

If anybody can provide a brief explanation and some example it will be really great and would help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item data allows you to associate any data you want to each item of your list control. This data is most of the time a pointer to some data structure.

For example in an email application you have a list control containing all received emails. Each item contains for example the sender, the subject and the date. The item data would contain a pointer to some data structure which contains the whole mail text amoung other information.

Answer (score 3):

The method `GetItemData()` is used in association with the method `SetItemData()` to allow a `CListCtrl` or a `CTreeCtrl` to have associated with items or nodes in the control some data.

The idea is that when populating the list or tree with nodes you can also assign a data item to the node using `SetItemData()` which can be retrieved by using `GetItemData()` when processing a selection event. The associated data may be something like a pointer to an object or an identifier of some sort which is the key to data stored in a collection such as a `std::map`.

The data type for the value retrieved with `GetItemData()` or assigned to an item with `SetItemData()` is a `DWORD_PTR` (see [DWORD and DWORD_PTR on 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867904/dword-and-dword-ptr-on-64-bit-machine) for a discussion on `DWORD_PTR`).

Another coincidence is that the `SendMessage()` and `PostMessage()` Windows API function have the `LPARAM` parameter, e.g. `SendMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`which is the same size as a `LONG_PTR` which is a `long` on x32 compile or `__int64` on x64 compiles (see [Microsoft Docs - Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg/windows-data-types)). And a `DWORD_PTR` is the same as a `ULONG_PTR` which just so happens to be a `unsigned long` on x32 compile or `unsigned __int64` on x64 compiles.

This means that the `DWORD_PTR` value from `GetItemDataa()` can be used as the `LPARAM` value in a `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()`. So you could use the `SetItemData()` method to associate a `LPARAM` type of identifier that the handler for a selection event for a `CListCtrl` or `CTreeCtrl` can then send to some other window or thread whose handle is known to communicate the selection event to some other part of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for beginners

For example, you have an int / string /struct or something else

```
struct foo
{
   ...
};

foo myData;    

list.SetItemData(nItem, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&myData));   
...  
myData = *(reinterpret_cast<foo*>(list.GetItemData(nItem)));
```

Note that SetItemData accepts a reference to an object, the object must be global,otherwise it will be destroyed